# how to integrate django app model with variables in other python file?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new in making RESTful API,

the goal is to make a RESTful API using django that can be access with flutter, the information that will be converted into JSON format by serializer.py is from variables that are processed in other script in python.

how to add the variable into the API? is it added in model.py? or maybe using POST method? I don't have any clue, because I just found the tutorial about GET method

Comment: If it is directly written, you can simply import that file and use the variable. Or if its in models, you will need to make a db query to get the variables